# On Invoice and Memos after release we have enabled custom fields both header and footer but while modifying the balance is updating with wrong value

Tags: acumatica

I had a requirement to enable some custom fields both header and footer if status is closed and balance = 0 then if we modify any footer field value on persist delegate setting the value for the modified field and updating Transactions cache (sample code below) then the balance 0 is getting updating with the value of Invoice total field.

```
public class KWARInvoiceEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<ARInvoiceEntry>
    {
[PXOverride]
        public void Persist(Action del)
        {            
            if ((Base.Document.Cache.GetStatus(Base.Document.Current) == PXEntryStatus.Inserted || Base.Document.Cache.GetStatus(Base.Document.Current) == PXEntryStatus.Updated))
            {
                foreach (ARTran items in Base.Transactions.Select())
                {

                    if (Base.Document.Current.DocType == ARDocType.Invoice)
                    {
                        if (Base.Document.Current.Released == true)
                        {
                             Base.Transactions.Cache.SetValue<ARTran.curyTranAmt>(items, items.CuryTranAmt);
                        }
                    }
                        Base.Transactions.Update(items);
                }
            }
            del();
        }
   }
```

[image: Before modifying any field in the grid, see the balance value]

[image: After modifying grid field, see the balance value]

Comment: What's the main issue, total not refreshing properly? If so does it refreshes after reloading the page? Does changing the values in Persist delegate saves them to database? After reloading page do you see the new values saved by Persist delegate?

Comment: The main issue is balance value is changing from 0 value to Invoice total value when we call persist delegate, but i observed that when we call base action after our custom logic then the balance value is changing. Can you guide me please how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

This happens inside the ARInvoiceEntry.ARTran_RowUpdated event. Normally in Acumatica, you cannot update released transactions so no additional conditions there and once you are trying to update any value and save transaction - balance will be calculated the same way as for balanced document.

```
protected virtual void ARTran_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    ARTran row = (ARTran)e.Row;
    ARTran oldRow = (ARTran)e.OldRow;
    if (row != null)
    {
        if ((!sender.ObjectsEqual<ARTran.branchID>(e.Row, e.OldRow) || !sender.ObjectsEqual<ARTran.inventoryID>(e.Row, e.OldRow) ||
            !sender.ObjectsEqual<ARTran.baseQty>(e.Row, e.OldRow) || !sender.ObjectsEqual<ARTran.curyUnitPrice>(e.Row, e.OldRow) || !sender.ObjectsEqual<ARTran.curyTranAmt>(e.Row, e.OldRow) ||
            !sender.ObjectsEqual<ARTran.curyExtPrice>(e.Row, e.OldRow) || !sender.ObjectsEqual<ARTran.curyDiscAmt>(e.Row, e.OldRow) ||
            !sender.ObjectsEqual<ARTran.discPct>(e.Row, e.OldRow) || !sender.ObjectsEqual<ARTran.manualDisc>(e.Row, e.OldRow) ||
            !sender.ObjectsEqual<ARTran.discountID>(e.Row, e.OldRow)) && row.LineType != SOLineType.Discount)
            RecalculateDiscounts(sender, row);

        if (row.ManualDisc != true)
        {
            var discountCode = (ARDiscount)PXSelectorAttribute.Select<SOLine.discountID>(sender, row);
            row.DiscPctDR = (discountCode != null && discountCode.IsAppliedToDR == true) ? row.DiscPct : 0.0m;
        }

        if ((e.ExternalCall || sender.Graph.IsImport)
            && sender.ObjectsEqual<ARTran.inventoryID>(e.Row, e.OldRow) && sender.ObjectsEqual<ARTran.uOM>(e.Row, e.OldRow)
            && sender.ObjectsEqual<ARTran.qty>(e.Row, e.OldRow) && sender.ObjectsEqual<ARTran.branchID>(e.Row, e.OldRow)
            && sender.ObjectsEqual<ARTran.siteID>(e.Row, e.OldRow) && sender.ObjectsEqual<ARTran.manualPrice>(e.Row, e.OldRow)
            && (!sender.ObjectsEqual<ARTran.curyUnitPrice>(e.Row, e.OldRow) || !sender.ObjectsEqual<ARTran.curyExtPrice>(e.Row, e.OldRow))
            && row.ManualPrice == oldRow.ManualPrice)
            row.ManualPrice = true;

        if (row.ManualPrice != true)
        {
            row.CuryUnitPriceDR = row.CuryUnitPrice;
        }

        // BALANCE WILL BE CALCULATED HERE!!!
        //
        TaxAttribute.Calculate<ARTran.taxCategoryID>(sender, e); 

        //Validate that Sales Account <> Deferral Account:
        if (!sender.ObjectsEqual<ARTran.accountID, ARTran.deferredCode>(e.Row, e.OldRow))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.DeferredCode))
            {
                DRDeferredCode defCode = PXSelect<DRDeferredCode, Where<DRDeferredCode.deferredCodeID, Equal<Required<DRDeferredCode.deferredCodeID>>>>.Select(this, row.DeferredCode);
                if (defCode != null)
                {
                    if (defCode.AccountID == row.AccountID)
                    {
                        sender.RaiseExceptionHandling<ARTran.accountID>(e.Row, row.AccountID,
                            new PXSetPropertyException(Messages.AccountIsSameAsDeferred, PXErrorLevel.Warning));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a result, you just need to override ARInvoiceEntry.ARTran_RowUpdated event and disable calculation for the released document. Something like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class ARInvoiceEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<ARInvoiceEntry>
{
    public delegate void EventDelegate(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e);

    [PXOverride]
    public void ARTran_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e, EventDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        if (Base.Document.Current.Released != true)
        {
            baseMethod.Invoke(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```